# Как передать данные через Bundle в фрагмент?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-bundle

Как передать данные через Bundle в статический фрагмент из Activity?

Activity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");

        Fragment1 fragobj=new Fragment1();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

Frament.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myValue = bundle.getString("name");

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,  "My Bundle contain "+ strtext);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);


    }

}
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#77ff0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="frag1_text">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.mxl

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO I am ACTIVITY "/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.my_app.one.fragment_bundle.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="fragment1">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вылетает с ошибкой на строчке    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

bundle = null

Comment: Уберите фрагмент из разметки и добавляйте через фрагмент менеджер,  тогда все получится

Answer (score 2):

У тебя все реализовано через fragment.
Проще в разметке указать так

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fmContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

В активити в onCreate или где удобно

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");

Fragment1 fragobj=new Fragment1();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.fmContent, fragobj)
.commit();
```

в фрагменте желательно проверять:

```
if (getArguments != null && getArguments().containsKey("name")) { 
//do smth
}
```

Comment: «Как передать данные через Bundle в **статический** фрагмент из Activity?»

Comment: Для статического можно так сделать:
В фрагменте добавить публичный метод
`public void setData (Yurdata data) {
}`
Из активити вызвать `((MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id)).setData();`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать статический метод, который будет создавать фрагмент и отдавать его вызывающему объекту.

```
 public MyFragment extends Fragment {   
   private static final String BUNDLE_CONTENT = "bundle_content"   

   public static MyFragment newInstance(final String content) {   
     final MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();   
     final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();   
     arguments.putString(BUNDLE_CONTENT, content);   
     fragment.setArguments(arguments);   

     return fragment;   
   }   

   private String content;   

   public MyFragment() {
     //default constructor
   }   

   //В onCreate() мы прочитаем переданный Bundle
   @Override   
   protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {   
     if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(BUNDLE_CONTENT)) {     
       content = getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_CONTENT);  
     } else {  
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be created through newInstance(...)");  
     }  
   }   
   ...   
 }
```

Таким образом, вызов фрагмента будет вот таким:

```
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance("something");
```

И фрагмент получит информацию

Comment: content = null  и FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo   на этапе инициализации layout   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be created through newInstance(...)

Comment: Покажите код, которым создаёте. Должно быть что-то вроде MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance("something");

Comment: source code : https://github.com/arsen100/Fragment_with_Bundle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/my/bundle_fragment/MyFragment.java